# E11000 duplicate key error collection Mongodb + Springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am still receiving an error message despite ensuring that all necessary fields have been filled out for updating existing records.

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: E11000 duplicate key error collection:

 medicalLibraryAPICollection.setVersion(1L);
                        
 MedicalLibraryAPICollection result = null;
result =medicalLibraryAPICollectionRepository.save(medicalLibraryAPICollection);
```

Comment: If the MongoDB server is issuing `E11000 duplicate key error`, then at least two values are identical for a field with a unique index.  I'd first determine if my indexes are correct and then possibly look at my field values.